# Is there any way to to debug a script running in a terminal using Pycharm?

Tags: python, debugging, pycharm

I was wondering, if it's possible.
I running my scripts using special runner in command line.
so the command looks like:

> runner.exe /path to scripts/

Does anybody know if i can set some breakpoints in scripts, execute my runner using above command in Pycharm Terminal and actually debug step by step?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Trying to hand-make a debugger is next to impossible, but it can be done. Think if this script outline:

- Find the path of the script
- Copy a temporary file of the script
- Go to each line where the breakpoints are
- Append a line to stop the script, such as `; quit(-1)` - But make sure that it not appended in between a command! **(see below)**
- Run the script
- Print out some debug code - but what?

Now, say, you have two lines, such as so:

```
55 print(someVar, someOtherVar +
56     someReallyLongVariable, orExpression(thatYouHaveTo, addAnotherLine))
```

And you add a breakpoint at line 55. Now it is:

```
55 print(someVar, someOtherVar + ; quit(-1)
56     someReallyLongVariable + orExpression(thatYouHaveTo, addAnotherLine))
```

And you would get the error:

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In your command prompt. While this is not impossible, it's better downloading some software that can do this, such as, my favorite Python IDE, [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) Community *(free)* edition. PyCharm can add breakpoints in your code and actually execute it step by step.

While I hope you download an IDE, if you're going to make a debugger by scratch, good luck. You're going to need it.

Comment: I actually use pycharm, but i run my script using special handwritten runner, i run it directly in pycharm terminal, and i can't figure out how to debug with break points in my case

Comment: You can find out about breakpoints [in the PyCharm help docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/breakpoints.html?search=break), along with [debugging in general](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/help/debugging.html?search=break). <br/> If you can't read it right now, you click to the left of the line you want to add breakpoints and click on the bug to the right of the run button to debug the code and stop at the breakpoint.

Comment: i know how to use debugger in Pycharm for a regular script, i need to know the way how to debug py script if it has been ran by some other program in my case by a runner